# Вывести текст из бинарного "01" кода

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Привет всем! Нужно декодировать из двоичной системы, то есть, дан бинарный код и я должен его расшифровать и вывести полученные символы на экран(текст). Писать на чистом С++, не используя битовые операции.

```
01010100 01001111 00100000 01000010 01000101 00100000 01001111 01010010
00100000 01001110 01001111 01010100 00100000 01010100 01001111 00100000
01000010 01000101
```

Comment: Где ваша попытка решить? Где ваш код?

Comment: Пока думаю, как сделать. Думаю написать через #define и переписать нужные символы таблицы ASCII, а вот что в коде писать, пока не знаю.

Comment: Откровенно говоря, непонятно, что и в каком виде подается на вход.

Comment: Мне даны символы в двоичной системы

Comment: Вы используете **Managed C++**?

Comment: Да, нужно написать программу на С++

Comment: На **C++.NET**? Или **чистый C++**? В этом вопрос был.

Comment: В Питоне: `''.join([chr(int(bits, 2)) for bits in Path('бинарные 01-коды.txt').read_text().split()])` -> `TO BE OR..`

Comment: связанный вопрос: [convert bitset to ASCII String](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13219683/4279)

Comment: На чистом С++, а не на .NET

Comment: Так, я понял что именно мне надо, мне нужно написать программу на С++ .NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы прочитать байты, представленные как 8-битовые ascii "01"-строки, [можно использовать `std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_ltltgtgt2). [Метод `.to_ulong()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11068204/4279) позволяет оригинальный байт вытащить:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
  for (std::bitset<8> bits; std::cin >> bits; )
    std::cout << static_cast<unsigned char>(bits.to_ulong());
}
```

[Пример](http://ideone.com/hsB0CC):

```
$ g++ bits-to-ascii.cc   -o bits-to-ascii
$ ./bits-to-ascii <<<'01010100 01001111 00100000 01000010 01000101 00100000 01001111 01010010'
TO BE OR
```

Comment: А не используя битовую систему, можно сделать?

Comment: @JZ_52 что такое "битовая система", "битовые операции" в вашем понимании? Код в ответе это чистый c++.

Comment: Так, я глупый человек и задал вопрос не зная в чём различие между С++ и С++ .NET. Так вот, программу мне нужно написать(сделать), на языке С++ .NET

Comment: @JZ_52: вы имеете в виду [C++/CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI)?